# jQuery - Where do I split the array before I add to combobox?

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, split

I'm trying to add the contents of a JSON file into a combo box. That works great, however some of the lines of the combobox have multiple values (e.g. 'hindi, english, french' all on one line) due to there being multiple values within some of the fields outputted in the JSON. I'm trying to split the array before injecting it into the combobox so that each value is on its own line but I'm not sure where to put the split array function. Can anybody point me in the correct location?  Thanks!

```
 $('#combolist-languages').html(function () {

            var ret = '<option value="-1" selected>Select language_</option>',
                u = user.slice(),
                arr = [];

            (function get() {
                if (u.length) {
                    var v = u.shift();      

                    if ($.inArray(v.Languages, arr) == -1) {

                        arr.push(v.Languages);
                        ret += '<option value="">' + v.Languages + '</option>';
                    }
                    get();
                }
            }());

            return ret;
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I completely understand you, but I think you're over thinking it

```
$('#combolist-languages').html(function () {

    var ret = '<option value="-1" selected>Select language_</option>',
        arr = [];

    $.each(user, function(i, v) {
        if ($.inArray(v.Languages, arr) === -1) {
            arr.push(v.Languages);
            ret += '<option value="">' + v.Languages + '</option>';
        }
    });

    return ret;
});
```

Comment: The reason is because the database has multiple values in for some of the entries. When the JSON retrieves the data and injects it into the combobox field, the lines where there are multiple values in the database are all in one option value - I'm trying to get them onto one line each.

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on your JSON file structure, but I'm guessing you can use the function is_object and is_array to find if the values are individual.

I'm guessing right after var v = u.shift(); you could:

```
if(is_object(v)){
    $.each(v.split(','), function(index, item){
        arr.push(item.Languages);
        ret+= '<option value="">' + item.Languages + '</option>';
    }
}
```

Now this might be wrong because I really don't know how your JSON object is constructed.